# Jquery Dialog Custom UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have this button and div tag:

```
<input type="button" onclick="popUp();" /> 
  <div id="codeId" style="display=none">
    <p id="msg"></p>
    <input id="code" name="code" type="text"></input>
  </div>
```

And when the user click's, it calls the function popUp(). Within the function I have a dialog UI that I want to display both the paragraph text and input box but my problem is that only one or the other show but not both. Here is my function popUp() with the dialog UI:

```
function popUp(){
var confirmationCode;
var code;

 if (code == "") {
    //Get randomly generated 6 character code
    code = code = Math.random().toString(36).slice(2, 8);
    for (var i = 0; i < code.length; i++) {
        var rand = Math.round(Math.random());
        if (rand === 1) {
            code = code.slice(0, i) + code[i].toUpperCase() + code.slice(i + 1);
        }
    }

    var msg = "Please enter the code " + code + " below.";

    $(function(){
       $("#codeId")
        .dialog({
            modal: true,
            width: 500,
            height: 400,
            buttons: [{
                Ok: function(){
                    $(this).dialog("close")
                }
            }],
            close: function(){
                confirmationCode = document.getElementById("code").value;
                if (confirmationCode === null) {
                        return false;
                    } else if (confirmationCode !== code) {
                        alert("The code does not match. Please try again.");
                        return false;
                    }else{
                        return;

                }
            }
        });

       $("#msg").html(msg);
    });
  }
 }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For one, `style="display=none"` is invalid. Also, why are you calling the equivalent of `document.ready` inside the `popUp` function?

Comment: I'm not sure why you think the css property is wrong. I'm actually using that and it works. Secondly, I'm running it that way because I didn't want to declare another variable for the actual .dialog(). Also once the dialog closes it will call another function.

Comment: the css property is syntactically wrong. the correct syntax is "display: none", it probably works anyway because there's no content to display inside the div, so the browser renders it with 0 height. What titus meant by the "equivalent of document.ready" is, I think, that you can simply remove the function wrapper $(function(){}); you don't need to declare any variable.

Comment: That's weird because I was getting the error message "cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'close'. And when I did some searching the reason that came up was that actual .dialog() needed to be initialized but by using the $(function(){}) that took care of that.